# Best way to mirror duplicate a rigged object?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, mirror, parent

okay so I'd been working on this Bird wing rig and had achieved success in finishing it, But i had only created it one wing. So now i have to make a duplicate for the wing on the other side and also mirror the armature in a way that the same functionality remains. is there a quick way to do that?, because if i have to repeat the entire process again for other one im screwd.

edit: writing the way i made the rig

the feathers you see each one of them have 2 constraints targetted to their adjacent neighbors, this allows for the spread out function and fit in function

the feathers are divided into two groups, one is PARENTED to the farthest object from the bird (the one that looks like a triangle), and the other group is also parented but to its neighboring object which is the second object from the bird.

both of those above objects are parented as BONE RELATIVE to the armature.

im also sharing the blendfile in a minute
here
[Blend file download](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1506/)
 [image]

Comment: Hello... you should indicate the particular way you made the rig, because the answer is not the same for a "traditional" rig (if this is the following of yesterday question).

Comment: @lemon okay just edited the question, and also provided the blend file. tell if there's bad news so i can do it the long way asap because i cannot afford to waste much time with this.

Comment: The point here is : you have 20 objects (wing and feathers) for one armature. And a mirror (mirror modifier) needs to be applied for each. If (mirroring manually) you select all, duplicate and mirror (X global in object mode), that will be equivalent to "scale X -1" so the rig becomes bad...

Comment: so after appliying mirror modifier to each of tho objects i still would need to setup the constraints right?

Comment: The mirror modifier will mirror from the center point of each object (and the center points here are not set correctly for that)

Comment: sorry I was wrong : you can set a mirror object in the modifier (not only the center) but this is still to be defined for each

Comment: never mind dude looks like ill have to take the long shot with this. still if you get something lemme know.

Comment: well I just can say "I did it"... but this cannot be considered as a real answer (deparenting, mirroring, reparenting...) and something is still bad (try to rotate and alt+R, you'll see... I dont know why). If this can help : [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1507" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1507/)

Comment: Hey.. you actually did it!!!!, and that problem, yeah it had been there long before its some sort of bug, happens in the original wing too. Thanks god you saved me some trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few explanations about the method to do it, but I have found nothing conventional to apply here on this initial particular (but well working) way of rigging a wing.

This was mainly manual editing (so not sure to remember all the steps) :

- define a center and set a center bone at this location
- parent the first wing bone to this center bone
- rename the bones with .LEFT as suffix, select them all and "symetrize" to obtain the .RIGHT bones
- duplicate wing parts and feathers and scale X, -1, with the center previously defined as pivot
- Edit each part of the right wing in order to arrange the normals
- Parent (with automatic weights) the wings (not the feathers) with the armature
- For the feathers (on the right), select them by group (object mode) in order to bone parent to the corresponding wing part

And the result as given in the comments above : [image]

Nothing "magical" !!